# app that checks on schoolsite if new notes are posted

Tags: android

Hi my name is Mikos and i am from a country far away.
Me and hunderds of other students must log in and check everyday on the schoolsite if our new note is posted. I would like to build an app that checks that automatically and  gives us a notification. Is this possible? For the site you need to log in to enter.

I have zero knowledge of programming but have loads of time on my hands and would like the challenge. I would like some tips of how where i can start this journey.

Greetings

Comment: Hi there! check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use always use Google's [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). They provide a lots of cloud services. Some of them are Database, Cloud Storage, Authentication and many more.

- You can connect your app to Firebase using Android Studio's Firebase assistant. **Go to Tools -> Firebase**